# How can I fix "no signal" issue with a VGA output on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, vga

I'm using an HP EliteBook running Ubuntu 20.04. The laptop has a Display output on one side and a VGA output on the other side.

I am trying to set up a 3 monitors display. When I connect my two extra monitors on both outputs, Ubuntu Settings, under "Displays", tells me that I have indeed 3 monitors connected. However, the VGA port only states "Unknown Display", and the monitor shows "no signal".

Using a Display/VGA adapter, I have been able to test each of the screens and cables. Every component works fine in a 2 monitors configuration when using the Display output. I can't get any of the screens to work in a 2 monitors configuration using the VGA output.

I have tried `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` but found no drivers to install.

Thanks in advance for helping me understand the issue, and hopefully fix it.

EDIT :

```
$ sudo lshw -c video

  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:128 memory:e0000000-e0ffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: Does the laptop's specification EXPLICITLY say that it will drive all three monitors at the same time? It may well be that it is either one, not both.

Comment: Well I can't be sure for now, but Ubuntu's Settings app correctly identifies when I try to plug in a second (and third) monitor. 

The issue seems to be with the VGA output : the presence of a second monitor is acknowledged, but the monitor displays "no signal" and the Settings app identifies any monitor as "Unknown Display". To be clear : the VGA output doesn't display anything, even when it's the only output being used. 

Each of the monitors work flawlessly when plugged via the Display / VGA adapter, which excludes a faulty cable or monitor.

Comment: From what you say; at least one of these is broken or incompatible: monitor, cable, port, laptop internal electronics, driver. And I'd say it is impossible to tell which if any (remotely). Try "Ubuntu install media" in "Try mode" - if that doesn't make it work;  Bring into a shop and ask them to help analyze the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "try mode" ? Like from a bootable USB key ?

Comment: Ubuntu install media has a "Try mode". Boot the media and you will get it onscreen; click on it. In a minute you will have Ubuntu running and able to handle your input; e.g. partitioning and formatting disks and whatnot

Comment: After additional research, I came to the conclusion that it is probably a hardware issue. I'm still puzzled as to why the computer detects when I plug something in, but I've tried both a Linux and a Windows bootable key without making any progress.